# Java if-statement being skipped

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

The method below takes in a string and a pattern and returns *true* if they match each other. A '.' matches 1 char and a '*' matches 0 or more (e.g. `expMatch("abc", "a.c")` should return *true*). I added a bunch of print statements to see where I went wrong and it seems like the if statement is being skipped even if the `str.length() == 1`.

I call it with `System.out.println(expMatch("abc", "a*c"));`

Here is the code:

```
public static boolean expMatch(String str, String pat)
{   
    if (str.charAt(0) == pat.charAt(0) || pat.charAt(0) == '.')
    {
        System.out.println("in if");
        System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(pat.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(str.length());
        if (str.length() == 1)
            return true;
        expMatch(str.substring(1), pat.substring(1));
    }

    else if (pat.charAt(0) == '*')
    {   
        System.out.println("in else");
        System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(pat.charAt(0));
        if (str.length() == 1)
            return true;
        if (str.charAt(0) == pat.charAt(1)) //val of * = 0
            expMatch(str, pat.substring(1));
        else if (str.charAt(1) ==pat.charAt(1))
            expMatch(str.substring(1), pat.substring(1));           
    }

    return false;           
}
```

and the output is:

```
in if
a
a
3
in else
b
*
in if
c
c
1
false
```

Even if the length is 1 it skips the if? Any idea why?
P.S. I'm not looking for the solution, just why the if statement is being skipped.

Comment: I suggest you add more logging - I'm sure you're just confusing yourself because the output is hard to understand with the recursion involved.

Comment: You don't return the value of the recursive calls, so those values are just thrown away. Instead, after the recursive call returns, you always return false.

Comment: The `if` statement is `skipped` because you have a bug and you don't yet fully understand what you're doing.   That's normal for a newbie.  Learn how to debug by using your IDE's facilities and using `println` statements.  You'll get it if you work at it.

Comment: string length 1 works for me....ahh its a bug, see Toms comment

Comment: You're returning `true` in the innermost recursion call (is that grammatically correct?). The "outer" calls (that are "wrapped" around the inner call) ignore that returned value and perform that next statements of your method. At the end, each one of them reaches this line: `return false;`.

Comment: You have another logical bug (not only the bug others pointed out). Working code provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is logically incorrect even if you apply the fixes the others suggested. Try this test case:

`System.out.println(expMatch("abddddc", "a*c"));`

This is because when you encounter a `*` in the pattern, you have no way to know how many characters "to eat" from the search string.

To say the least, you need a loop somewhere, not just an `if`. Let me try to fix it for you (not sure if it's possible though, not sure if you always know which path to take, I mean in your recursion). Think some more about it. Here is another unpleasant test case:

```
System.out.println(expMatch("adddcac", "a*c")); 
// the * needs to eat dddca (despite the c present in dddca),  
// it should not stop recursing there at that c
```

I think you need some sort of full search here.
Just an `if` or a `while` loop is not good enough.

**EDIT**: Here is a fixed version with a bunch of nasty tests. I think this is called *non-linear recursion* (as it's not a single path you try). Not 100% sure though about that term.

```
public class Test055 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println(expMatch("abddddc", "a*c"));

        System.out.println(expMatch("adcax", "a*c"));
        System.out.println(expMatch("adcax", "a*c*"));

        System.out.println(expMatch("adcacm", "*"));
        System.out.println(expMatch("adcacmmm", "a*c"));
        System.out.println(expMatch("adcacmmmc", "a*c"));
        System.out.println(expMatch("adcac", "a*c"));

        System.out.println(expMatch("adcacxb", "a*c.b"));
        System.out.println(expMatch("adcacyyb", "a*c.b"));
        System.out.println(expMatch("adcacyyb", "a*c*b"));

    }

    public static boolean expMatch(String str, String pat)
    {
        // System.out.println("=====================");
        // System.out.println("str=" + str);
        // System.out.println("pat=" + pat);

        if (pat.length() == 0 && str.length() > 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (pat.length() == 0 && str.length() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (pat.charAt(0) == '.'){
            return str.length() >= 1 && expMatch(str.substring(1), pat.substring(1));
        }else if (pat.charAt(0) != '*'){
            return str.length() >= 1 && pat.charAt(0) == str.charAt(0) && expMatch(str.substring(1), pat.substring(1));
        }else{
            // Now let's handle the tricky part

            // (1) Look for the 1st non-star in pattern
            int k=-1;
            char ch = ' ';
            for (int i=0; i<pat.length(); i++){
                if (pat.charAt(i) != '*'){
                    k = i;
                    ch = pat.charAt(k);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (k==-1){
                // (2A) only stars found in pattern, OK, any str matches that
                return true;
            }else{
                // (2B) do full search now checking all  
                // possible candidate chars in str that 
                // match the char ch from pattern
                for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
                    if (str.charAt(i)==ch){
                        boolean b = expMatch(str.substring(i+1), pat.substring(k+1));
                        if (b) return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You always return false from the method at the very end.  You are calling expmatch recursively but never using the return value.  The code comes in to the first if, recurses (because length is not 1) and upon returning will go to the final return statement which returns false.

Comment: thank you. that actually makes sense. I see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a return before your expMatch() calls - because the `false` comes from your last line `return false;`

What happens is this:

- you call  expMatch() with the two Strings.
- you enter the if clause
- the if clause enters expMatch() recursively
- you enter the else clause
- the else clause enters expMatch() recursively
- you enter the if clause again
- you leave the expMatch() method
- you leave the other expMatch method
- false is returned